# Volume inside sphere and cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume in the first octant ($x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0$) inside the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 9$ and the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=2x$.

*My solution attempt is as follows*:

The region of integration is the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=2x$, which in polar coordinates is just $r = 2\cos(\theta)$ so the region of integration is $$-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},\, 0 \leq r \leq 2\cos(\theta)$$ and since we're in the first octant, the region is $$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},\, 0 \leq r \leq 2\cos(\theta)$$
So the volume is

$$ V = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{2\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{9-r^{2}} \,rdr\,d\theta$$

I'm having trouble calculating the integral from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mustafa: Your set-up is correct. The first layer of integration is easy, but then you end up with an elliptic integral.

Comment: I would start with a change of variable: $9-r^2=x$ with $dx=2rdr$. The integral of $\sqrt x$ should be trivial

Comment: @Andrei: That far *is* trivial. Do the next integral, please.

Comment: @TedShifrin Numerically :)

Comment: It would be easy to calculate the integral over $\theta$ if the radius of sphere would be 2 (or similarly scale the cylinder)

Comment: As the other commenters have pointed out, this has no closed form solution in terms of elementary functions. If this is a problem you've gotten from a professor, perhaps they intended the problem to be the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ or the circle $x^2+y^2=3x$.